# Visual Studio stuck in code view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wysiwyg, designview

I am currently trying to create a Windows Form Application where I need to see the WYSIWYG view, rather than the code view. I understand there are a lot of threads with potential fixes but everything I have tried doesn't work. I have tried clicking on it in the Solution Explorer and pressing F7 but it still just displays the code.

If someone could give me the answer or point me to a thread I have not found before with an answer, that would be great.

EDIT: Programming in C# not HTML

Comment: What kind of application? WPF? Winforms? ASP?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Windows Form

Comment: have you try Shift-F7 to view, F7 to code?

Comment: Have you tried... Right-Click on the Form in the Solution Explorer... there you should be able to "View Code" or "View Designer"

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't run it yet and just created a bare class, the class itself should inherit `Form` from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;    

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
   }
}
```

You should be able to get into the designer once that's done.